# Trouble with installing Pandas, Matplotlib, NumPy, pytz for Python OS X

Tags: python, macos, pandas, anaconda, miniconda

I tried installing Pandas for Python via Anaconda and Miniconda.

I've tried it for both Python 2 and Python 3. The installing via Anaconda and Miniconda both seem successful (Anaconda created a launcher on desktop and when Miniconda completed installing the command `conda list` gave me a list where it said that Pandas and other modules were correctly installed). But when I run my code `import Pandas` or `import matplotlib` with Python Launcher, it says:

> ImportError: No module named pandas.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `But when I run my code import Pandas or import matplotlib with Python Launcher ` - This step may need more information. What exactly are you doing here?

Comment: I made a code using Visual Studio Code with just one line: import pandas. Just to see if it would import pandas. I tried the same thing in IDLE: import pandas, and got the same error.

Comment: And you followed these instructions? http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration#python-tools-for-visual-studio-ptvs

Comment: Thanks! I did not use any of those IDE's, but it gave me a hint of how to solve the problem! In Python Launcher, you have the ability to change the default interpreter. I didn't know this. I changed this to Anaconda and the code worked!